# Constantinople fork: my local Ropsten is not on the same branch of Etherscan

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan

With the Constantinople fork few days ago (Oct 2018) my local ropsten node is not the same as Etherscan.

I have geth 1.8.3-stable

> my node: block hash of 4248333 is 0xb24b6a6...
>
> ropsten.etherscan: block hash of 4248333 is 0xe725eff6...

How do I get back on the same branch as ropsten.etherscan ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you have to wait for the confirmation of the successful fixing of the consensus problem, then init (resync from the genesis block).

I’m not sure that the network is ok now: they found the bug, but I could prefer to wait for further confirmation before to re-sync.

Comment: I updated  geth to 1.8.17-stable
I'm still on the wrong branch.
Is there a specific version that I should use ?
Which version is used by Etherscan ?

Comment: Friend of mine... the ropsten has been divided in many chucks because the problem that the costantinopole test generated. It is not a problem of Geth version, any of them is ok. The problem is to sync with the right blockchain of the many. If you truly did not understand my previous answer, simply do not do nothing and wait, because you cannot solve.

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly found a solution:

1) remove database:

> geth --testnet removedb

2) start geth with no discover mode (it will not look for peers)

> geth --testnet --syncmode=fast --nodiscover

3) add peers manually

> admin.addPeer("enode://f4642fa...")

I tried several suggested nodes to connect to Ropsten Etherscan but I finnally get the right one with an Infura node:

https://notes.ethereum.org/s/SJE9O2ksQ#Ropsten-Byzantium-gtConstantinople-fork

Now I'm back on Ropsten Etherscan